# React-Redux - object props update doesn't re-render child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a calendar using react and redux.

I have a parent component(App) that pass to a child component(MonthlyCalendar) props called events.

events is an object.
Each value in events is an array.
Any events update from redux, re-render the parent component but not the child component that use the events.

The first life-cycle of the child component is the only one that runs, after that no update life-cycle. Even though the props has changed from empty object to object with properties.
I saw that this is a known issue - object props, but none of the solutions worked.
If it's a duplicate I'm sorry i feel like i tried them all.

I tried destructuring for the events in the child and in the parent.

I tried using JSON.parse and stringfy.

Adding a key based on the length of the events props in the child.

I removed all setState and actions that might manipulate the state, still the parent re-render but the child is not.
The check is done by console.log on each life cycle of the child component, which gets printed only once when the component mounts. And when debugging it is shown that the updated events reach render function of the parent.

**The parent component - App.tsx**

```
class App extends React.Component<AppProps> {
  state = {
    events: {},
    weekStarter: 'sunday',
    isTimeShown: true,
    isTimeZoneShown: true,
    isTodayButtonStyleSeconday: true,
    locale: 'en',
    timeZone: '',
  };

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.fetchEvents = this.fetchEvents.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.Wix.Styles.getStyleParams((styleParams: any) => {
      this.updateStyle(styleParams);
      console.log('getStyleParams', styleParams);
    });
    window.Wix.addEventListener(
      window.Wix.Events.STYLE_PARAMS_CHANGE,
      (styleParam: Object) => {
        console.log('STYLE_PARAMS_CHANGE', styleParam);
        this.updateStyle(styleParam);
      },
    );
  }
```

...

```
render() {
    const { t, events } = this.props;
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/index"
          render={() => (
            <MonthlyCalendar
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
              events={{...events}}
              handleMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
              isTimeZoneShown={this.state.isTimeZoneShown}
              isTimeShown={this.state.isTimeShown}
              locale={this.state.locale}
              //timeZone={this.state.timeZone}
              isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={this.state.isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/settings"
          render={() => (
            <Settings
              fetchEvents={this.fetchEvents}
              initialState={this.props.initialState}
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/mobile"
          render={() => (
            <MonthlyCalendar
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
              events={events}
              handleMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
              isTimeZoneShown={this.state.isTimeZoneShown}
              isTimeShown={this.state.isTimeShown}
              locale={this.state.locale}
              isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={this.state.isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({});
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  isConnect: state.settings.isConnect,
  userName: state.settings.userName,
  events: state.settings.dates,
  calendarsList: state.settings.calendarsList,
  googleSettings: state.settings.googleSettings,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

**Child - MonthlyCalendar.tsx**

```
class MonthlyCalendar extends React.Component<
  IMonthylCalendarProps & WithTranslation,
  IMonthylCalendarState
  > {
  monthlyCalendarRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  public static defaultProps = {
    locale: 'en',
    weekStarter: WeekStartersEnum.Sunday,
    events: [],
    isTimezonesOpen: true,
    isTodayButtonStyleSeconday: true,
    isTimeZoneShown: true,
    isTimeShown: true
  };

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    console.log('[constructor] props.events: ',props.events)
    const timezone = moment.tz.guess();
    const dateObject = moment().tz(timezone, true);
    this.state = {
      dateObject,
      timezone,
      isTimezonesOpen: false,
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('[shouldComponentUpdate] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    return true
  }
```

...

```
getCalendar() {
    const mutableEvents = {...this.props.events};
    const { dateObject } = this.state;
    const beforeFillers = this.getMonthBeforFillers(dateObject, mutableEvents);
    const days = this.getDays(dateObject, mutableEvents);
    const afterFillers = this.hasAfterFillers(beforeFillers, days) ?
      this.getAfterMonthFillers(dateObject, mutableEvents) : {};
    return { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers };
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('[componentDidUpdate] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== prevProps.locale && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('[componentDidMount] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    this.props.locale !== 'en' && await this.updateLocale();
  }

  render() {
    const { t, weekStarter, isTodayButtonStyleSeconday, isTimeZoneShown, isTimeShown, events: propEvents } = this.props;
    const eventsKey = Object.keys(propEvents).length;
    const { dateObject, timezone, isTimezonesOpen } = this.state;
    const { days, beforeFillers, afterFillers } = this.getCalendar();
    const month = dateObject.format(t('Google_Calendar_Picker_Month'));
    const timezoneSelected = moment().tz(timezone).format(t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected'));
    const timezoneSelectedTitle = t('Google_Calendar_Timezone_Selected_Title', { timezoneSelected });
    console.log('[render] props.events: ',this.props.events)
    return (
      <TPAComponentsProvider value={{ mobile: false, rtl: false }}>
        <div key={eventsKey} className={classes.MonthlyCalendar}>
          <CalendarControllers
            isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            todayClicked={this.todayClickedHander}
            onPreviousClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(false)}
            timeToDisplay={month}
            onNextClicked={() => this.timePickerClickedHandler(true)}
            onTimezoneChange={this.timezoneChangeHandler}
            timezone={timezoneSelectedTitle}
            isTimezonesOpen={isTimezonesOpen}
            openTimezones={this.openTimezones}
            closeTimezones={this.closeTimezones}
            isTimeZoneShown={isTimeZoneShown}
          />
          <MonthTable
            weekStarter={weekStarter}
            days={days}
            beforeFillers={beforeFillers}
            dateObject={dateObject}
            afterFillers={afterFillers}
            renderCell={(
              time: any,
              events: any,
              cellRef: any,
              handleEventClick: any,
              setExpendedEvent: any,
              expendedEvent: any,
              isOutsideClicked: any,
            ) => (
                <MonthlyCell
                  events={events}
                  handleEventClick={handleEventClick}
                  time={time}
                  cellRef={cellRef}
                  expendedEvent={expendedEvent}
                  isOutsideClicked={isOutsideClicked}
                  setExpendedEvent={setExpendedEvent}
                  isTimeShown={isTimeShown}
                />
              )}
          />
        </div>
      </TPAComponentsProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(MonthlyCalendar);
```

any help would be appreciated

**EDIT 1**

i added forceUpdate to the parent component at componentDidUpdate, still no re-render of child component (MonthlyCalendar):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps: AppProps) {
    const prevEvents = JSON.stringify(prevProps.events);
    const currentEvents = JSON.stringify(this.props.events);
    if ( prevEvents !== currentEvents) {
      this.forceUpdate()
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 2**

maybe its a route related issue. i read article about rendering component in route: [https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-pass-props-in-react-router/#:~:text=Passing%20function%20as%20a%20component%20props%20in%20Route%20component&text=Internally%2C%20react%20router%20use%20React,just%20updating%20the%20existing%20component.](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-pass-props-in-react-router/#:%7E:text=Passing%20function%20as%20a%20component%20props%20in%20Route%20component&text=Internally%2C%20react%20router%20use%20React,just%20updating%20the%20existing%20component.)

added render with props and {...props} still no go:

```
<Switch>
        <Route
          path="/index"
          render={(props: any) => (
            <MonthlyCalendar
            {...props}
              weekStarter={this.state.weekStarter}
              events={{...this.state.events}}
              handleMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
              isTimeZoneShown={this.state.isTimeZoneShown}
              isTimeShown={this.state.isTimeShown}
              locale={this.state.locale}
              //timeZone={this.state.timeZone}
              isTodayButtonStyleSeconday={this.state.isTodayButtonStyleSeconday}
            />
          )}
        ></Route>
```

**EDIT 3**

it seems that if i take out the route, everything is working and the child re-render. do anyone have an explanation for this behaviour ?